# Google translate does not translate menus

Tags: google-translate

I am using the "Google translate my page". I placed the generated by google translate code and placed on my web-site (http://jewelryfashionstyle.com). It's all fine but the menu items and some other text do not get translated. What could be the cause?

Sorry, forgot to add - it can't be translated only from other languages that are available under the google translate's dropdown.

Comment: They are getting translated for me without issue.

Comment: Yes,me too.but the layout of menu has changed.