# Google translate pages does not translate whole page

Tags: google-translate

I am asking this question again, as no one was able to answer it before. I am including some updates.

Web-page - http://jewelryfashionstyle.com/sv/
In the right top corner there is google translate thingy. It translates the whole page correctly from any language but Swedish. In Swedish version, the main menu and some other items do not get translated. The "from" language is set correctly.

I tried everything, even removed all tags from menu (only the menu item words remained) but for some reason it does not translate the menu. I tried placing the menu in different place, tried to remove the javascript that animates it - no luck.

Does anyone have any idea what could the problem be? Please, help. I've been looking for the solution for a week already :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google translate does not translate menus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259462/google-translate-does-not-translate-menus)

Comment: Editing your old question would have bumped it to the front anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The problem doesn't come from google translate, the problem comes from the personn that makes the page, the website does not use google translate to translate the page.
if you insert your page in google translate website, you will have the exactly the same elements that are translated in russian and swedish

Comment: Wow, you must be a google fan :) Prejudice never shows much reason. I have placed the Google Translate box that was provided by Google itself. The page is made from template. Please, don't leave comments if you have no idea about the solution

Comment: I translate your website from english to swedish [there](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=sv&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=jewelryfashionstyle.com%2Fen)
and from english to russian [there](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=fr&sl=en&tl=ru&u=http%3A%2F%2Fjewelryfashionstyle.com%2Fen)
In both cases the search icon is not translated

Comment: Please, read carefully what I wrote in the question. In the right top corner of the web-site (my web-site, not google translate web-site) there is a "Select language" box. Under it there are 3 flags. When you switch to swedish (the last flag) and then use the "Select language" thingy, the main menu does not get translated.

Comment: yes, I understood, I'm trying to understood why there js script gives different output than their website

Comment: Maybe try to change 'sv' into 'sw' in the google translate script

Comment: no. iso code for swedish is SV. The same in google translate. Anyway - I tried, no luck